# How do you use an applescript variable in C++ (Xcode)?

Tags: c++, applescript, xcode7

```
char* cmd=(char*) "osascript -e 'set myFile to choose file with prompt \"Please select 
a '.txt' file:\" of type {\"public.plain-text\"}'";
system(cmd);
```

In the code above, I want to use the applescript variable "File" in C++, or somehow store its value in a C++ variable. Is there a way to do this?
I tried this:

```
char* filename;
char* cmd;
sprintf(cmd, "osascript -e 'set %s to choose file with prompt \"Please select 
a '.txt' file to encrypt:\" of type {\"public.plain-text\"}'", filename);
system(cmd);
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: If you just run the `osascript` command just on its own in Terminal, it prints the selected file onto standard output, so I guess you would need to use `popen()` instead of `system()` to run the osascript and then read its output maybe - I suspect there must be a better way though.

Comment: And I think you can't use `"File"` as it is probably reserved - you may need `myFile` or somesuch.